# What is the best way to avoid accidental repeated clicks on Any btn?

Tags: android, button, android-jetpack-compose, lazyvgrid

My problem was accidentally repeated clicks on LazyVerticalGrid element which is resolved by using:

`var enabled by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }` and `val scope = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycleScope`.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        state = lazyVGState,
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 100.dp)
    ) {
        items(groupMap.keys.toList().sorted()) { item ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.clickable(
                    enabled = enabled,
                ) {
                    enabled = false
                    navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(
                        CITY_WEATHER_LIST,
                        cityList
                    )
                    navController.navigate(Screen.CityForecastScreen.route)
                    scope.launchWhenStarted {
                        delay(10)
                        enabled = true
                    }
                },

                ) {
                // some elements
            }
        }
    }
```

If i don't use enabled state, user may open an element for couple times.
Looking for community opinion.
THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation framework provides an up to date and synchronous view of the navigation state in your app, so the safest way to prevent multiple clicks is by checking if you are still in the navigation destination hosting your LazyList by using

```
navController.currentDestination
```

and comparing that against the LazyList screen identifier.

Comment: Taking your advice, I wrote this line: `navController.currentDestination == navController.findDestination(Screen.WeatherForecastScreen.route)`. It is working fine). Hope I didn't disappoint you & understood you correctly.

Comment: That's exactly what I described, glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
​fun​ NavController.​safeNavigate​(​direction​:​ ​NavDirections​) {​    
       currentDestination?.getAction(direction.actionId)?.​run​ { navigate(direction) }
​}
```

And instead of `navController.navigate`, use `navController.safeNavigate` with the same arguments.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but I couldn't find a way to use NavDirection. THX.